# Using Class to Call a User Input

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a class to store a user input but seem to be running into some issues. I would normally just use `input()` but the class I'm taking is asking us to build a class that represents an object of interest. Below is the code that I've developed so far but I feel like I'm making a class for the sake of making a class. Am I missing something here?

````
import requests

class Requirement:
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address = input("enter address here")
        return address
        

address = input('Enter Address')

loc = Nominatim(user_agent="GetLoc")

getLoc = loc.geocode({address})

# printing address
print(getLoc.address)

# printing latitude and longitude
print("Latitude = ", getLoc.latitude, "\n")
print("Longitude = ", getLoc.longitude)```
````

Comment: You can't return anything other than None from \_\_init\_\_ also, as a matter of style, asking for input within the class constructor is not good practice. Rather acquire the data elsewhere in your code then pass values to the class constructor. Your code, as shown, is not runnable

Comment: Do you have any recommendations or docs to look at how to pass values to the class constructor? Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: your class is already coded to accept an initialisation parameter - *address*

Comment: How would you rewrite my code?